# How to obtain 2 separate plots in seaborn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, seaborn

I have a big function which output is a dataframe and 2 charts. Something like this:

```
summary = pd.concat([mean, std], axis=1)
chart1 = sns.tsplot(sample['x'].cumsum())
chart2 = sns.tsplot(summary['mean'])
result = [summary, chart1, chart2]
return result
```

Everything works fine, except, I only get one chart with the two time series in it. I would like to get two separate charts. How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feed explicit matplotlib objects to `tsplot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def whatever(mean, std, *args, **kwargs):
    summary = pd.concat([mean, std], axis=1)
    chart1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    sns.tsplot(sample['x'].cumsum(), ax=ax1)

    chart2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    sns.tsplot(summary['mean'], ax=ax2)
    result = [summary, chart1, chart2]
    return result
```